# How to write Dockerfile to serve Angular app and Node server

Tags: node.js, angular, docker, google-cloud-platform

My Angular app runs fine locally but I haven't figured out how to do the same with a Docker image. Outside of Docker, the UI runs on port 4200 with `ng serve` and the API serves data from 8080 with `node server.js`.

My Dockerfile is set up so it can get the Node server running and available on 8080, but the Angular UI won't run. I've tried several options but right now I have:

```
FROM node:14.17.3
COPY package*.json ./
EXPOSE 4200 8080
RUN npm install -g @angular/cli
RUN npm install --only=production
COPY . ./
RUN ng serve
CMD ["node", "server.js"]
```

It fails on `ng serve` with the error: `The serve command requires to be run in an Angular project, but a project definition could not be found`. I do have an angular.json file in the root. I'm not sure what I am missing. I read that `ng serve` shouldn't be used in this situation but the alternatives I've seen haven't made a difference.

Workspace:
[image]

EDIT 8/10/21: Based on the answers here and a bunch of research, this will display the UI with nginx:

```
FROM node:12.16.1-alpine as build
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm ci --only=production
COPY . .
# RUN npm install -g @angular/cli
# RUN npm run build --prod
FROM nginx:1.15.8-alpine
COPY --from=build /usr/src/app/dist /usr/share/nginx/html
# CMD ["node", "server.js"]
```

However, the npm run build step fails because ng is not found despite installing @angular/cli. I have to run this manually to build the dist folder. And I can't run `node server.js` alongside this. It seems I can only get the front end or back end, not both.

Comment: Could you post a screenshot of your workspace?

Comment: `ng serve` is only for **development**

Comment: @robert I've read that but haven't found the prod alternative.

Comment: I think you need to tell `node` to serve the `js` files in `/dist` once Angular has run a build. Like @robert says, `ng serve` is a development command.

Comment: "prod" alternative can be any http server (Apache, nginx, node) which can serve static files. After you compile Angular project the result is few js, html and css files typically in `dist` folder. You need to copy the content of that folder under your webserver.

Comment: I agree with robert & godhar btw; rather than `ng serve`, you should use `ng build --prod` to build the project and then serve that(the `dist` folder contents) from a server (node in your case)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I figured out a solution that will run the full application. Most answers here focus on running the front end (the nginx suggestion was helpful). It seemed a Docker container could enable the UI or server but not both. I came across Docker Compose, which will run the front and back ends in separate images. My solution:

Dockerfile.ui

```
# Define node version
FROM node:12.16.1-alpine as build
# Define container directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
# Copy package*.json for npm install
COPY package*.json ./
# Run npm clean install, including dev dependencies for @angular-devkit
RUN npm ci
# Run npm install @angular/cli
RUN npm install -g @angular/cli
# Copy all files
COPY . .
# Run ng build through npm to create dist folder
RUN npm run build --prod
# Define nginx for front-end server
FROM nginx:1.15.8-alpine
# Copy dist from ng build to nginx html folder
COPY --from=build /usr/src/app/dist /usr/share/nginx/html
```

Dockerfile.server

```
# Define node version
FROM node:12.16.1-alpine
# Define container directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
# Copy package*.json for npm install
COPY package*.json ./
# Run npm clean install, prod dependencies only
RUN npm ci --only=production
# Copy all files
COPY . .
# Expose port 8080 for server
EXPOSE 8080
# Run "node server/run.js"
CMD ["node", "server/run.js"]
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:
  server:
    build: 
      context: ./
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.server
    container_name: server
    ports:
      - 8080:8080

  ui:
    build: 
      context: ./
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.ui
    container_name: ui
    ports:
      - 4200:80
    links:
      - server
```

`docker-compose up` will build out an image for server and UI and deploy concurrently. I also resolved the `ng not found` errors by installing dev dependencies, particularly `@angular-devkit/build-angular`.

This tutorial helped me figure out Docker Compose: https://wkrzywiec.medium.com/how-to-run-database-backend-and-frontend-in-a-single-click-with-docker-compose-4bcda66f6de

Comment: can u please help me on this.. angular and node server runs on which port..  also CMD ["node", "server/run.js"] how this command can be run?

Answer (score 4):

Use below command at the end to run `ng serve` with host `0.0.0.0` which means it listens to all interfaces.

`CMD ["ng","serve","--host", "0.0.0.0"]`

But I would suggest using ngInx.

Steps to follow:

1. Create a docker file under the root of your project, and add the below code. It takes care of: downloading dependencies, building angular project, and deploy it to ngInx server.

```
#Download Node Alpine image
FROM node:12.16.1-alpine As build

#Setup the working directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/ng-app

#Copy package.json
COPY package.json package-lock.json ./

#Install dependencies
RUN npm install

#Copy other files and folder to working directory
COPY . .

#Build Angular application in PROD mode
RUN npm run build

#Download NGINX Image
FROM nginx:1.15.8-alpine

#Copy built angular files to NGINX HTML folder
COPY --from=build /usr/src/ng-app/dist/pokemon-app/ /usr/share/nginx/html
```

2. Build docker image:

`docker build -t my-ng-app .`

3. Spinning the docker container with below command expose your app at port 80

`docker run -dp 3000:80 my-ng-app`

Check out my article on this - https://askudhay.com/how-to-dockerize-an-angular-application, and please let me know if you still have any questions.

Comment: This solution comes the closest to actually working. I have two problems:
1. npm run build never works. ng is still undefined. I have to run it manually first and build the dist folder.
2. This does not run the cmd ["node", "server.js"] which runs the API. I've tried adding the CMD line but I get "node: executable file not found in $PATH: unknown"

Comment: The written solution worked for me, however, I would like to bring that further into a compose file. But anyway, thx Udhay, good tip!

Answer (score 0):

I think updating this line

```
COPY . ./
```

with

```
COPY . ./app
```

should solve that error. It appears that the node "volume" is in that folder.

Otherwise setting the workdir also seems like a solution:

```
FROM node:14

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package*.json ./
...
```

Source: https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/nodejs-docker-webapp/

Comment: I tested it but the ng error remains as is.

Comment: Updated my answer, let me know if this works

Comment: Same result. Fails on ng serve.

Comment: How about replacing `RUN ng serve` with `CMD ng serve`? you might want to comment out the `node server.js` one to test